# Why didn't Harry Potter die from the basilisk venom in COS?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, basilisk

In The Chamber of Secrets, Harry gets bitten by the basilisk. Also, we know Harry IS a horcrux. Basilisk venom one of few things that can destroy horcruxes. So why didn't Harry go to the white place like in The Deathly Hallows? One of the main things we know is that objects destroyed by basilisk venom are destroyed IMMEDIATELY. Harry got bit by the basilisk, so why didn't he die when he got bit? The only answer we have right now is that it had to travel through his bloodstream to either his heart or wherever Voldemort's soul hit that night in Godric's Hollow.

Comment: Does anyone know this answer without it having to run through his bloodstream? Please let me know.

Comment: heres what your looking for http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9770/29220

Comment: The short answer to this question is actually nothing to do with Horcruxes. 'Because Fawkes' healing tears saved him' basically covers it.

Comment: Also, as a general FYI, [Harry is *not* a Horcrux](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/could-the-sorting-hat-have-told-dumbledore-that-harry-was-a-horcrux). :)